# Bio.PDB.Superimposer - what is RMS?

Tags: biopython

I am comparing two structures and a bit confused about meaning of the result parameters:
What is the value returned saved in super_imposer.rms ?
I guess it's RMSD, but why is it not written as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super_imposer.rms` is indeed the root-mean-square deviation.

If you consult the [source of `Bio.PDB.Superimposer`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/de12c5e08fc44d9c158954bb4b1d5f98cfb84c69/Bio/PDB/Superimposer.py#L45), you'll see that the `rms` attribute is the result of a call to [`get_rms()`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SVDSuperimposer.SVDSuperimposer-class.html#get_rms). The docstring for `get_rms()` reads:

> Root mean square deviation of superimposed coordinates.

The Tutorial does say that ["The RMSD is stored in the `rmsd` attribute,"](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec195) however. No idea why this discrepancy exists.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! :)